# Oracle only time constraint

Tags: oracle

I have two columns `start_time` and `end_time`. The types are `DATE`.

I would like to make a constraint that provides the `start_time` is lower than `end_time`. And the date part doesn't matter.
So if the two variables are:
Start: 2017-01-02 11:40
End: 2017-01-01 12:40

It returns True

How can I do that?

Comment: Compare `to_char(start_time, 'HH24:MI:SS' )` to `to_char(end_time, 'HH24:MI:SS' )`

Comment: it isn't duplicate cause it is a CONSTRAINT not a QUERY and I DONT WANT TO CONVERT IT TO CHAR it is insane

Comment: Why is it insane to compare them as strings? Your question implies you know how to make a check constraint but just don't know how to deal only with the time portions; the linked question (plus Tim's comment) shows how to do that part.

Comment: As I know there is some difference between constraints and querys. But i am not sure. it isn't looking to be a good solution to convert  dates to strings to compare them. There should be a way to that without type conversion. I don't know the Oracle, but in any other programming language, it would be a mistake to do it this way.

Comment: But you aren't comparing dates, you're comparing the least significant parts of dates, so you have to extract/manipulate/convert them somehow. You could manipulate them to the same date and still compare as dates, or could end up with two numbers to compare, but I'm not sure why either would be better here. Comparing things as string when there is a more suitable data type is indeed usually not good - but there is no 'time' data type to use here, so strings are adequate, since you can get the time in a safe-to-compare format.

Answer (score 3):

One of the date format masks is `'sssss'` which gives the number of seconds after midnight. So you can enforce your constraint like this:

```
 alter table your_table 
    add constraint start_end_range_ck as 
    check (to_number(to_char(start_date, 'sssss')) < to_number(to_char(end_date, 'sssss')))
/
```

Or you want `<=`, it's not clear from your question.

Comment: The OP didn't want the comparison logic to convert away from date, though, so probably he won't like this solution either ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do this; I like APC's `sssss` approach, but Tim's suggestion of using strings also works:

```
check (to_char(start_time, 'HH24:MI:SS') < to_char(end_time, 'HH24:MI:SS'))
```

Or you can get the fractional part of each day by subtracting the truncated value from itself (which essentially gives you two numbers which are 1/86400th of APC's):

```
check (start_time - trunc(start_time) < end_time - trunc(end_time))
```

If you really really want to treat them as dates you could add those numbers back on to nominal dates:

```
check (date '1900-01-01' + (start_time - trunc(start_time))
  < date '1900-01-01' + (end_time - trunc(end_time)))
```

or modify one values date part based on the difference between them, which is perhaps closest to your (possibly misplaced) desire to avoid type conversion:

```
check_times check (start_time + (trunc(end_time) - trunc(start_time)) < end_time)
```

Or if you really wanted to be explicit you could pull out each time element and compare them individually:

```
check (
  extract(hour from cast(start_time as timestamp)) < extract(hour from cast(end_time as timestamp))
  or (
    extract(hour from cast(start_time as timestamp)) = extract(hour from cast(end_time as timestamp))
    and extract(minute from cast(start_time as timestamp)) < extract(minute from cast(end_time as timestamp))
  )
  or (
    extract(hour from cast(start_time as timestamp)) = extract(hour from cast(end_time as timestamp))
    and extract(minute from cast(start_time as timestamp)) = extract(minute from cast(end_time as timestamp))
    and extract(second from cast(start_time as timestamp)) < extract(second from cast(end_time as timestamp))
  )
)
```

but that's obviously starting to get a bit silly, and still does type conversion since you have to cast the dates to timestamps to be able to extract time components in the first place...